# Sending value from controller to Mail to view

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5

In my controller, I am trying send mail like this

```
$activationLink = $activation->GetActivationCode->ActivationLink;
\Mail::to($company)->send(new MLink);
```

I have a variable called activationlink, which I need to send it to the email

Mlink Mail class

```
public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('emails.mindbody')->with($activationLink);
    }
```

View file

```
<h2>Your activation link is : {{ $activationlink }} </h2>
```

It's not working this way, I get the activationlink is not defined error.

How can I pass the $activationLink from my controller, to the view file (the email that is sent)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add it in the constructor of MLink class like this :

```
private $activationLink;

public function __construct($activationLink)
{
    $this->activationLink = $activationLink;
}

public function build()
{
    return $this->view('emails.mindbody')->with($this->activationLink);
}
```

And  in the controller

```
$activationLink = $activation->GetActivationCode->ActivationLink;
\Mail::to($company)->send(new MLink($activationLink));
```

Or as mentioned by @Camilo you can set the visibility of `$activationLink` to public and remove `->with` keyword because you will have access to this variable in the view :)

Comment: Alternatively you can set `$activationLink` to be public and avoid the `with()` part.